# Exception when trying to retrieve user in Coevery.Core GetNavigation function

Tags: c#, orchardcms

In Coevery CRM (built on top of Orchard) I'm trying to retrieve the current logged-in user in the `FrontMenu.cs` class in `Coevery.Core` module. In the `GetNavigation` function I added my line of code to retrieve current user:

```
public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder) {

            var menus = Services.ContentManager.Query<TitlePart, TitlePartRecord>().OrderBy(x => x.Title).ForType("Menu").List().ToList();
            int firstMenuIndex = 0;
            menus.ForEach(c => {
                builder.AddImageSet(c.Title)
                    .Add(T(c.Title), (++firstMenuIndex).ToString(),
                        menu => {
                            string url = string.Format("#/{0}", c.Id);
                            menu.Url(url);
                            menu.Content(c);
                            menu.IdHint(c.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                            int menuIdex = 0;
                            var subMenus = _menuService.GetMenuParts(c.Id)
                                .OrderBy(menuPartEntry => menuPartEntry.MenuPosition, new FlatPositionComparer())
                                .ToList();
                            foreach (var subMenu in subMenus) {
                                var subMenuCotent = subMenu;
This is my line of code--->     var user = Services.WorkContext.CurrentUser;
                                var menuItemEntity = CreateMenuItemEntries(subMenu, url);
                                var moduleMenuItem = subMenu.As<ModuleMenuItemPart>();
                                var position = (++menuIdex).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                if (moduleMenuItem != null) {
                                    menu.Add(T(menuItemEntity.Text), position, item =>
                                        item.Url(menuItemEntity.Url).Content(subMenuCotent).IdHint(subMenuCotent.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), 
                                        new List<string>() {moduleMenuItem.IconClass});
                                }
                                else {
                                    menu.Add(T(menuItemEntity.Text), position, item =>
                                        item.Url(menuItemEntity.Url).Content(subMenuCotent).IdHint(subMenuCotent.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                                }
                            }
                        });
            });
    }
```

When I try to run the project, I get error compiling `Coevery.Core`.

Would appreciate any insights on how I can get the user details correctly.

EDIT:

Screenshot from solution for the location of FrontMenu.cs

[image]

Comment: First of all, I don't see any Frontmenu class in Coevery.Core, it is in Coevery.Perspectives module. Second of all, you should not change any core code, Orchard is setup to be able to override classes and not change any core code

Comment: @devqon I see, thank you for the hint. For the FrontMenu.cs, I have uploaded the screenshot for the solution, please check the updated question. Could you possibly have a different version of Coevery that has a different hierarchy of the classes? If so, can you please point me to where I can find it?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the compile error (probably in the logs)

Comment: @devqon This may sound silly, but while checking the compiler logs, I thought of rebuilding the single Coevery.Core project, and actually the code worked fine. From testing I discovered that if I edited the code I have to rebuild the parent project again, the solution build alone would throw out the exceptions. I would like to thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Good to hear :) but please bare in mind my comments on affecting Core code. Try to use Orchard's powers by overriding classes and functionality. This will also help you when you update the Core of the project

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I will definitely keep this in mind. Thanks again!